# Remotely update properties “cmis:creationDate and cmis:lastModificationDate”

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I need to update the ReadOnly properties on alfresco like 'cm:creator or cm:created' so I create a java-backed webscript:

```
public void onUpdateProperties(NodeRef nodeRef, Map<QName, Serializable> before, Map<QName, Serializable> after) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        try {
            Date d = sdf.parse("21/12/2012");
            cal.setTime(d);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        policyBehaviourFilter.disableBehaviour(nodeRef, ContentModel.ASPECT_AUDITABLE);
        nodeService.setProperty(nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_CREATED, cal);
        nodeService.setProperty(nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_MODIFIED, cal);
        nodeService.setProperty(nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_MODIFIER, "test");
        nodeService.setProperty(nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_CREATOR, "test");
        policyBehaviourFilter.enableBehaviour(nodeRef, ContentModel.ASPECT_AUDITABLE);
    }
```

everything works fine but i need to set properties with the remote values sent by the client side not only the local ones:

```
public Document createDocument(Folder folder,String name,String actId) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date d = sdf.parse("21/12/2012");
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.setTime(d);
        //properties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:document,P:cm:titled,P:cm:author");
        properties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, name);
        properties.put(PropertyIds.CREATED_BY, "createdBy");
        properties.put(PropertyIds.LAST_MODIFIED_BY, "modifiedBy");
        properties.put(PropertyIds.CREATION_DATE, cal);
        properties.put(PropertyIds.LAST_MODIFICATION_DATE, cal);
        properties.put("cm:title", "Title");
        properties.put("cm:description", "Description");
        properties.put("cm:author", "author");
        byte[] content = "Hello World!".getBytes();
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
        ContentStream contentStream = new ContentStreamImpl(name, BigInteger.valueOf(content.length), "text/plain", stream);
        Document newDoc = folder.createDocument(properties, contentStream, VersioningState.MAJOR);
        return newDoc;
    }
```

Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check out [this tutorial from JPotts](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/webscripts/tutorial/tutorial.html) to get familiar with [Webscript development](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/ws-overview.html).

In the mean time, as you can see in [here](https://github.com/jpotts/alfresco-developer-series/blob/master/webscripts/webscripts-tutorial-repo/src/main/java/com/someco/scripts/PostRating.java) you can fetch get parameters using this method : `WebScriptRequest.getParameter(String)` or even fetch an element from a json payload like this:

```
    String params = "{}";
    String myVar;
    try {
        params = IOUtils.toString(req.getContent().getInputStream(),
                "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // Handle exception properly
    }
    JSONObject postParams;
    try {
        postParams = new JSONObject(params);
        if (postParams.has("some-attribute")){
            myVar = postParams.getString("some-attribute");
        }
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // Handle exception properly
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot it works fine with java-backed webscirpt.